# ¿Cómo obtener los registros de una tabla y mostrarlos en una <div> por separado?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Me encuentro aprendiendo las consultas SQL y al momento soy principiante, la duda que tengo es, ¿se puede combinar un `SELECT DISTINCT` y un `GROUP BY` en la misma sentencia SQL?

`DISTINCT` elimina los duplicados, `GROUP BY` agrupa los registros de acuerdo a un campo determinado, es lo que yo entendí. Si mi entendimiento está mal,  ¿alguno de ustedes me lo podría explicar?

Por cierto, hago esta pregunta porque estoy haciendo uniones de tres tablas, es por eso formulé esta pregunta.

La estructura de mis tablas son las siguientes:

```
TABLE carrito
idCarrito VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
idCliente VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
idSesion VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
fechaHora DATETIME NOT NULL
aux INT NOT NULL

-----
TABLE contenido_carrito  
idContenidoCarrito INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
idCarrito VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
idCliente VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
idSesion VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
idArticulo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
codigoArticulo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
codigoAlterno VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
costo DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
unidades INT NOT NULL
subTotal DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
fechaDeRegistro DATETIME NOT NULL
aux INT NOT NULL

-----
TABLE articulo
idArticulo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
descripcionArticulo VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL
stock INT NOT NULL
fechaDeRegistro DATETIME NOT NULL
aux INT NOT NULL
------------
TABLE imagen
idImagen INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
idArticulo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
urlImagen VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
nombreImagen VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
orden INT NOT NULL
fechaDeRegistro DATETIME NOT NULL
aux INT NOT NULL

----------
TABLE cliente
idCliente VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
denominacion VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
nombre VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
apellidoPaterno VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
apellidoMaterno VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
fechaDeRegistro DATETIME NOT NULL
rfc VARCHAR(20) NULL
aux INT NOT NULL
```

En mi archivo: cliente_historial.php tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
$consultaPedidos =  $ConexionBD->query("
SELECT  DISTINCT carrito.idCarrito, carrito.idCliente, carrito.fechaHora, contenido_carrito.idArticulo, contenido_carrito.costo,contenido_carrito.unidades, contenido_carrito.subTotal, imagen.nombreImagen 
FROM carrito 
INNER JOIN contenido_carrito ON carrito.idCarrito = contenido_carrito.idCarrito
INNER JOIN articulo ON articulo.idArticulo = contenido_carrito.idArticulo
INNER JOIN imagen ON imagen.idArticulo = articulo.idArticulo
INNER JOIN cliente ON carrito.idCliente = cliente.idCliente
WHERE carrito.idCliente = '$idCliente'
                and carrito.idCarrito = contenido_carrito.idCarrito ORDER BY fechaHora;
 ");
 ?>

<div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="box box-danger">
                        <div class="box-header with-border">
                            <h3 class="box-title">Pedidos que realizaste</h3>
                            <br><br>
                            <!-- =====================================-->
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="box box-info">
                                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                                        <?php

                                        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaPedidos)) {

                                                echo '
                                            '.$rows["nombreImagen"].'
                                            '.$rows["costo"].'
                                            '.$rows["unidades"].'
                                            '.$rows["subTotal"].'
                                            '.$rows["fechaHora"].'

                                            ';

                                        }
                                        ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                 <div class="box-body no-padding">
              </div>
            <div class="box-footer no-padding">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

El problema es que me muestra la consulta de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver son registros que están regados, lo que pretendo hacer es que por cada pedido (de la tabla carrito , que por cierto tiene una PK que nunca se repite) se haga una divsión, y no logro hacer eso.
Aquí un ejemplo de cómo será
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada pedido (de la tabla carrito) que se haga se genera un PK, esa PK puede tener varios articulos. Por ejemplo

```
      Tabla carrito:
       idCarrito    idArticulo
       C00001        A23232
       C00001        A34345
       C00001        A54544
```

Nuevamente les planteo el problema; sacar ese pedido(idCarrito) y poner en una división, luego, si se encuentra otro idCarrito ponerlo en otra visión.
Espero me haya explicado.

Comment: Indica el esquema de las tablas y que es lo que quieres obtener exactamente

Comment: si es posible y su sentencia simple es select distinct campo
from tabla group by campo

Comment: @Rastalovely pero me marca error, es posible abrir un chat? para que le pregunte

Comment: ya te dijeron, Indica el esquema de las tablas y que es lo que quieres obtener. Sin eso, nadie jamas podrá ayudarte

Comment: En muchos casos son considerados _sinónimos_, [ver la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html). ¿Usarlos al mismo tiempo?, he probado y no da error, la pregunta es **¿para qué quieres usarlos al mismo tiempo?** [En este ejemplo](http://rextester.com/TVOF35144) la segunda consulta los usa al mismo tiempo, pero el `DISTINCT` lo único que hará será posiblemente ralentizar las cosas y nada más.

Answer (score 1):

Considero que son varias preguntas en una.

En esta respuesta trataré de aportar una solución que puede ser idónea para lo que quieres hacer.

La respuesta se enfoca solamente en la forma de consultar los datos. A partir de ese resultado, podrás trabajarlos en PHP para organizarlos como quieres.

La consulta sería algo así más o menos (no incluyo todos los campos por motivos de brevedad, la intención es que entiendas el concepto):

```
SELECT 
    cl.cliente, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('_',ar.descripcionArticulo, cc.costo) SEPARATOR '|') articulos
FROM
carrito_20170831 ca
INNER JOIN cliente_20170831 cl ON ca.idCliente=cl.idCliente
INNER JOIN contenido_carrito_20170831 cc ON ca.idCarrito=cc.idCarrito
INNER JOIN articulo_20170831 ar ON cc.idArticulo=ar.idArticulo
WHERE ca.idCarrito='C1'
GROUP BY ca.idCarrito;
```

Aquí consultamos los datos del carrito cuyo `id` es igual a `C1`.

Obtendremos en este caso los datos así:

```
cliente articulos
Pedro   Artículo 1_100.99|Artículo 5_85.10|Artículo 3_23.99
```

Si haces dos `explode` correctos de la columna `articulos`  (primero sobre `|` y dentro de ese `explode` sobre `_`, podrás presentar los datos  así:

```
Cliente: Pedro
Carrito: C1

-- Demás datos

Artículos:
Descripción    Costo
Articulo 1     100.99
Artículo 5      85.10
Artículo 3      23.99
```

Aplicando reglas CSS y leyendo el arreglo de datos que resulte de la base de datos, podrás diferenciar por cliente, por id de carrito o por lo que quieras... pero eso sería parte de otra pregunta, por eso decía que era muy amplia. No obstante, no es tan complicado lo que quieres.

Aquí te dejo un demo completo con una reproducción parcial de tus tablas, podrás hacer pruebas sobre el código. Al menos damos un primer paso: **resolver lo de la consulta SQL**. Espero te sirva.

#### [`Demo`](http://rextester.com/edit/TVOF35144)

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS carrito_20170831 (
                idCarrito VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                idCliente VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE   IF NOT EXISTS contenido_carrito_20170831 ( 
                idContenidoCarrito INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                idCarrito VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                idArticulo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                costo DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articulo_20170831 (
                idArticulo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                descripcionArticulo VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE   IF NOT EXISTS cliente_20170831 (  
                idCliente VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                cliente VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);


INSERT INTO carrito_20170831 (idCarrito, idCliente)
    VALUES 
    ('C1','CL1'),
    ('C2','CL2'),
    ('C3','CL3')
;


INSERT INTO contenido_carrito_20170831 (idCarrito, idArticulo, costo)
    VALUES 
    ('C1','A1',100.99),
    ('C1','A5',85.10),
    ('C1','A3',23.99),
    ('C2','A2',40.00),
    ('C2','A4',33.30)

;

INSERT INTO articulo_20170831 (idArticulo, descripcionArticulo)
    VALUES 
    ('A1','Artículo 1'),
    ('A2','Artículo 2'),
    ('A3','Artículo 3'),
    ('A4','Artículo 4'),
    ('A5','Artículo 5')
;    

INSERT INTO cliente_20170831 (idCliente, cliente)
    VALUES 
    ('CL1','Pedro'),
    ('CL2','Santiago'),
    ('CL3','Juan')
;    

SELECT 
    cl.cliente, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('_',ar.descripcionArticulo, cc.costo) SEPARATOR '|') articulos
FROM
carrito_20170831 ca
INNER JOIN cliente_20170831 cl ON ca.idCliente=cl.idCliente
INNER JOIN contenido_carrito_20170831 cc ON ca.idCarrito=cc.idCarrito
INNER JOIN articulo_20170831 ar ON cc.idArticulo=ar.idArticulo
--    WHERE ca.idCarrito='C1'
GROUP BY ca.idCarrito;
```

---

#### `Resultado:`

```
cliente     articulos
Pedro       Artículo 3_23.99|Artículo 1_100.99|Artículo 5_85.10
Santiago    Artículo 2_40.00|Artículo 4_33.30
```